# PHP mongodb aggregate query : result field not found

Tags: php, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I query mongoDB through PHP.
I make the following request:

```
cursor = $full_mappingsCollection->aggregate(array(
    array('$match' => array('species'=>$organism)),  
    array('$project' => array('mapping_file'=>1,'species'=>1,'_id'=>0)),
    array('$unwind'=>'$mapping_file'),
    array('$match' => array('$or'=> array(
        array('mapping_file.Transcript ID'=>new MongoRegex("/^$search/xi")),
        array('mapping_file.Plaza ID'=>new MongoRegex("/^$search/xi"))
    ),
    array('$project' => array("mapping_file"=>1,'species'=>1,'_id'=>0))
),
array('cursor' => ["batchSize" => 0]));
array_push($cursor_array, $cursor);
```

Before, I could display the results by iterating this way:

```
foreach ($cursor['result'] as $result) {
    echo "$result";
}
```

Today the field "result" no longer exists and I don't know how to display my results.

Any help will be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Edit : I found the answer. Wishing it could help someone:

```
foreach ($cursor['cursor']['firstBatch'] as $result) {
    echo "$result";
}
```